# Return to the page I last visited, after logging out

Tags: discussion

Quite often when I log out from a question page, it redirects to the home page. Why not return the user back to the last viewed page instead?

Comment: Dude seriously! whole point of logging out is to get out of the system so why would any want to log out an still be redirected to the last page he or she visited.

Comment: Interesting, but this would result in some non-standard behavior that goes against convention. Personally, I like going to the main page because I like to answer questions. Personal preference thing. Maybe we should have an option to set a default page?

Comment: [Because you can't handle the success!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207390/178816)